too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation (in included file)

I have a Qt project
Got this error in file "lab2.h" next to the line with the include directive (signed next to it)

#ifndef LAB2_H
#define LAB2_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QFrame>
#include "element.h" //too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation element.h:24:25note: error occurred here:Qt\6.7.0\mingw_64\include...


class lab2 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    QFrame *f;
    QLabel *label;
    QLineEdit *edit;
    QPlainTextEdit *box;
    QPushButton *add;
    QPushButton *del;
    QPushButton *first;
    QPushButton *last;
    QPushButton *all;
    QPushButton *exit;
    QPushButton *sum;

    lists my_list;
    element *q;

public:
    lab2(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~lab2();
public slots:
    void beg();
    void fi();
    void de();
    void la();
    void lla();
    void S();
};

class numi: public element{
public:
    int i;
    numi(int n):element(){
        i=n;
    }
    std::string show()override{
        std::string ret="";
        ret+=std::to_string(i);
        return ret;
    }
    ~numi() override{}
};

class numf: public element{
public:
    double f;
    numf(double m): element(){f=m;}
    std::string show()override{
        std::string ret="";
        ret+=std::to_string(f);
        return ret;
    }
    ~numf()override{}
};
#endif // LAB2_H


from file "element.h" with description of classes


#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

#include <string>


class element
{
public:
    element *p;
    element(){p=nullptr;};
    virtual ~element(){}
    virtual std::string show()=0;
};

class lists{
private:
    element *f,*l,*c;
public:
    lists();
    void add(element *q);
    ~lists();
    void del();
    std::string foreach();
    std::string sym();
    element *fist();
    element *last();

};

class E{
public:
    int e;
    E(int ae);
    std::string error();
};

#endif // ELEMENT_H

I realized after looking for similar problems that I had lost my arguments somewhere. I don’t quite understand where to look for the error

please read about [mcve]. Remove as much as your code as possible to still reproduce the error (and not introduce other unrelated ones). And please include the complete verbatim error message in the question, it has much more valuable information

Define the QT_NO_FOREACH macro or the broader QT_NO_KEYWORDS macro to turn off this footgun. QT_NO_KEYWORDS also disables the signals and slots macros which are nice to have, so I would not do that.

ok, my function had the same name as the foreach() macros. for simplicity instead of initialising #define I just renamed it to foreachLists()
